# How to stop others from downvoting my questions?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

**This is not the duplicate question. As in that** **question user got blocked. That is not the case**               **with me. ** As I joined math.stackexchange I have asked two questions. I was new at that time and didn't know how to write a question. Those questions are not too bad.

Then someone with lots of reputation points advised me to edit my questions with what I had attempted. And I did that. But still one of my questions is on hold. That's not the problem. Problem is that people downvoting again and again without telling a proper reason. Is there a way to stop that?

Here are the links of those questions:

- [Question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052181/to-find-bounded-area-using-definite-integrals)
- [Question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051393/to-find-area-using-definite-integral)

Comment: Post good questions.

Comment: @Martin James yes I know that now. But how to stop others to downvote my questions.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh Don't post any *bad* questions.

Comment: @Servy ok. But I want to know why they are downvoting. Any way to ask from them?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh No, there is not.

Comment: Learn from the lesson. You will be blocked by the system from posting additional questions if your posts keep attracting downvotes. Don't take downvotes personally unless it is serially downvoted by a user.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent downvotes, post good questions.
To prevent further downvotes, edit your question to improve it.
If that would take time, you could delete it first (if it hasn't received any answers yet), edit it, and then undelete it.

Every Stack Exchange site has a `/help/how-to-ask` and a `/help/on-topic` pages, tailored to each site, designed to help you ask good questions that will be well-received. You should read these carefully, and be very critical about what you post before posting. These pages link to further pages, which are also recommended to read.

On any mature site, you will also find questions very similar to yours,
if not perfect duplicates. Those can be good examples of what to do (if highly voted) and what not to do (if poorly voted).

If you want to be extra careful to avoid downvotes,
you could post your question on pastebin.com or gist.github.com and ask around in the site's chatroom to take a quick look and get advice for improvements.

Comment: I have edit my questions but still downvotes. And for me they are perfect now. And those who are downvoting doesn't tell reason so that I amend them.

Comment: If you don't understand why your question was poorly received, you could ask a question on the corresponding meta site, linking back to your question.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh You might think that they're perfect, but the downvotes are telling you that they are not, so you still have work to do to make them good questions.  There is lots of information out there on how to ask a good question.  Look through the help center, look at the FAQ's on meta, etc. and you'll find *lots* of advice on how to ask a good question.

Comment: _"...delete it first (if it hasn't received any answers yet), edit it, and then undelete it."_ Edit it in an external editor, undelete, and swiftly edit with your copy/pasted edit from the external editor. You can't edit on the sites themselves a question you have posted and self deleted until you undelete it.

Comment: Problem is that it has answers and on one question I also have accepted answer.